# ICCameraDevice delete after download with requestDownloadFile:... doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, macos, image-capture

I'm trying to get download from ICCameraDevice to work.  Mostly it does, but the "delete after download" option with ICDeleteAfterSuccessfulDownload doesn't seem to work.  Here's my code for downloading one item:

```
NSDictionary *downloadDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              [NSURL fileURLWithPath:reviewPath], ICDownloadsDirectoryURL,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], ICOverwrite,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:deleteAfterDownload], ICDeleteAfterSuccessfulDownload,
                              [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], ICDownloadSidecarFiles,
                              nil];
ICCameraFile *fileToDownload = [importItems objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"downloadDict == %@", downloadDict);
NSLog(@"importCamera == %@ (locked == %@)", importCamera, [importCamera isLocked] ? @"YES" : @"NO");

[importItems removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[importCamera requestDownloadFile:fileToDownload options:downloadDict downloadDelegate:self didDownloadSelector:@selector(didDownloadFile:error:options:contextInfo:) contextInfo:NULL];
```

The download dictionary seems well-formed, according to the log:

2021-07-26 12:39:45.529142-0400 ... downloadDict == {
ICDeleteAfterSuccessfulDownload = 1;
ICDownloadSidecarFiles = 1;
ICDownloadsDirectoryURL = "file:///Users/bhaller/Desktop/dltest_exif4/";
ICOverwrite = 0;
}

And the camera says that it supports single-file delete (`ICCameraDeviceCanDeleteOneFile`), and is not locked:

```
2021-07-26 12:39:45.529600-0400 ... importCamera == 
ICCameraDevice <0x108a8c080>:
  delegate                      : <0x10882d4c0>
  deviceRef                     : 0x10000024
  connectionID                  : 0x00000000
  deviceID                      : 0x02000007
  name                          : Canon PowerShot ELPH 110 HS
  locationDescription           : ICDeviceLocationDescriptionUSB
  iconPath                      : systemSymbol.camera
  softwareInstallPercentDone    : 100.000000
  modulePath                    : /System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/PTPCamera.app
  moduleVersion                 : (null)
  moduleExecutableArchitecture  : 0
  type                          : 0x00000101
  UUIDString                    : 34443344-3235-3037-3646-333134434142
  persistentIDString            : 34443344-3235-3037-3646-333134434142
  autolaunchApplicationPath     : 
  capabilities                  : ICCameraDeviceCanTakePictureUsingShutterReleaseOnCamera
                                  ICCameraDeviceCanDeleteOneFile
                                  ICCameraDeviceCanAcceptPTPCommands
  shared                        : NO
  transportType                 : ICTransportTypeUSB
    usbLocationID               : 0x02240000
    usbProductID                : 0x3241
    usbVendorID                 : 0x04a9
    usbIntefaceClass            : 0x00
    usbInterfaceSubClass        : 0x00
    usbInterfaceProtocol        : 0x00
  timeOffset                    : 0.000000
  hasConfigurableWiFiInterface  : N/A
  isAccessRestrictedAppleDevice : NO

 (locked == NO)
```

The download succeeds, and the file is created on my machine and is well-formed.  No problems.  And yet the file is not deleted from the camera.  What am I missing?

Also, in passing: the *second* time that my app connects to this camera, I get this log:

```
2021-07-26 12:41:22.265175-0400 ... Command 'ICACopyObjectPropertyDictionaryCmd' failed with error = -1.
```

Perhaps this is somehow related, although it does not happen on the first connection to the camera.  I've tried googling `ICACopyObjectPropertyDictionaryCmd` and got pretty much zilch; Google seems to know nothing at all about this.  I'm puzzled by the `ICA` prefix, since ImageCapture uses `IC`; is this something internal and thus undocumented?  I can't even figure out how to break on this error; it *looks* like output from `NSLog()`, but apparently it is not (nor `NSLogv()`).  It has me stumped.

[ADDED:] I just got another mysterious console log, which I haven't seen before, after doing several downloads from the same camera in one session:

```
2021-07-26 12:53:23.779117-0400 ... Command 'ICARegisterForEventNotificationCmd' failed with error = -1.
```

No idea what this one means either; again, Google sheds no light.

Comment: Recommend to set a breakpoint using lldb br set -n "processDeleteOne:object:" See if it gets called and stopped on it. The dissasembly shows that only AVI, MOV, CRW, MRW, TIF, MP4 can be deleted. I am not even familiar with this but a quick suggestion.

Comment: On top use br set -n "-[ICDDownloadFileImp process]" or just br set -n "process"

Comment: Hmm.  Not sure what I would do afterwards, though, even if the breakpoint gets hit.  (What does the dog plan to do if it catches the car?)  :->  What I need is either (a) a reason for the problem, such that I can fix it or work around it, or (b) knowledge that it is simply a bug, in which case I'll log it on Apple.  Looking like (b) so far...

Comment: Are you sure that delete breakpoint is hit? Those extensions I got from disassembly ->are they documented?  Feedback assistant -> it can take years till they fix it or even acknowledge bug.

Comment: Have you tried: other option values like `ICOverwrite = YES` and/or `ICDownloadSidecarFiles = NO`, an exception breakpoint, `-[ICCameraFile requestDownloadWithOptions:completion:]`, `requestDeleteFiles:deleteFailed:completion:`? Is `didDownloadSelector` called, any errors?

Comment: Is your project a copy of the [CameraBrowser sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CameraBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007761)? Is a table view using bindings?

Comment: Try a breakpoint on `ICACopyObjectPropertyDictionary` and `ICARegisterForEventNotification`.

Comment: @MarekH None of those breakpoints work.  processDeleteOne:object: and -[ICDDownloadFileImp process] give "WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations", while "process" gives 119 locations and thus is apparently not set.  No, the documentation says nothing about only specific extensions being deleted, as far as I have seen.  Yes, Feedback Assistant is slow and unsatisfying; it would be nice to find a workaround for this!

Comment: @Willeke `ICOverwrite = YES` and `ICDownloadSidecarFiles = NO` made no difference to the bug.  Exception breakpoints for all Obj-C and C++ exceptions did not get hit.  The two ICA breakpoints you suggested did not get hit.  No, it's not a copy of CameraBrowser, and it doesn't use bindings.  `didDownloadSelector` does get called, no errors.  Using `requestDownloadWithOptions:completion:` instead makes no difference, no errors.  So far, no dice.

Comment: Seems like it is simply a bug, if a rather odd/surprising one (did they not test this at all?), and nobody seems to have a workaround.  I'll log a bug on Apple and move on.  Oh well, thanks for the ideas.